# redirect code not working in itemreceiver

Tags: c#, sharepoint

how can i redirect to a page from sharepoint?

i have this within the itemadded event receiver for a list:

```
SPUtility.Redirect("http://mysite", SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current );
```

but on debugging HttpContext.Current is null so it doesnt do any redirect when a list item is added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ItemAdded event occurs asynchronously (i.e. sometime after the item is added). It's executing on a separate thread that doesn't have access to the HttpContext for the current request (and therefore you won't be able to send a response to tell the user's browser to redirect).

This might work in the ItemAdding event receiver - it executes on the same thread that adds the item to a the list. I'm not sure that it's safe to perform a redirect since it might prevent other underlying code to be executed in SharePoint.

This was echoed by [Lars Fastrup in one of your previous questions (redirect using itemreceiver sharepoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049585/redirect-using-itemreceiver-sharepoint). Consider implementing the solution he recommends there.

Comment: perfect answer. Seeing as ItemEventReceivers occur Asynchronously, it could theoretically be possible that a user gets redirected after say 30 seconds while he is already doing something else. Imagine his face when all of a sudden he finds himself on a different page :-P